# cakephp, How to change controller url name

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way to change name of generated url based of controller eg:
if i visit controller `ArticlesController` and action of it `add`
url generated is `/articles/add`. Can i change it somehow ? To look like this `/pages/add`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change it. On `routes.php`, you can add a connection route:

```
Router::connect('pages/:action', array('controller' => 'articles'));
```

Please look at the documentation for further information: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html